# left alignment of multicolumn inserts extra space

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

how do I get `\multicolumn` to align left? I always get a small space at the beginning of the row. Here's a code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D.{\mbox{.}}{#1}}      

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}       
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.3} d{2.3} @{}}                                       
\toprule \toprule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\textbf{Benchmark} \\                                                                
$\quad $Net effect & 0.73 & 0.59  \\     
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Benchmark}} \\                                                                
$\quad $Net effect & 0.73 & 0.59  \\     \bottomrule \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\end{table}     

\end{document}
```

The second 'Benchmark' is not fully aligned to the left. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}{....}` perhaps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that the main `tabular` has the first column alignment specified as

```
@{} l
```

which removes the column spacing to the left of the `l`eft-aligned column (due to `@{}`). `\multicolumn{.}{l}` re-formats the column specification to `l` *without* the removal of the column spacing on the left. So you should either use

```
\begin{tabular}{ l ... }
  ...
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{..}
  ...
\end{tabular}
```

or

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l ... }
  ...
  \multicolumn{3}{@{} l}{..}
  ...
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your column specification you have `@{}` at the start: this suppresses that space to the left of the first column. You need to add this into the column specifier you pass to multicolumn. When added to your code you get the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D.{\mbox{.}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.3} d{2.3} @{}}
\toprule \toprule
\textbf{Benchmark} \\
$\quad $Net effect & 0.73 & 0.59  \\
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Benchmark}} \\
$\quad $Net effect & 0.73 & 0.59  \\     \bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```